# Proving that $G=H$, given that $G \circ F = id_A$ and $F \circ H = id_B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given this relations:

$$ F : A \rightarrow B, $$ 
$$ G : B \rightarrow A, $$
$$ H : B \rightarrow A, $$

we also know that:

$$ G \circ F = id_A$$
$$ F \circ H = id_B$$

Is it true that G=H?

I've been struggling with this for a while, and this is what I tried out. Take an element: $$a \in A, F(a) = b \in B$$
$$G(b) = a $$ (since $ G \circ F = id_A$ )

$$ \forall a \in A \hookrightarrow F(a) = b \in B, G(b) = a $$
$$ \forall b' \in B \hookrightarrow H(b') = a' \in A, F(a') =  b' $$

Let's suppose the oppposite, that $G \neq H$ :

$$ \implies \exists b \in B \hookrightarrow G(b) \neq H(b) $$
$$ \implies \exists a \in A \hookrightarrow F(G(F(a))) \neq F(H(F(a)))$$

And this a contradiction, because $ G(F(a))=a, F(H(F(a)))=F(a)$, so this should hold true: $ F(G(F(a))) = F(H(F(a)))$

Therefore, $G=H$.

So, my question is, is this proof correct? I'm not used to this type of problem, so I don't know if my approach is okay.

Edit: typo

Comment: The proof seems all right to me (except a little typo when you write : ∀′∈↪(′)=′∈,(′)=′ , you should write F instead the second H ;) ). The approach is ok ! The same ideas can be used by avoiding to use a proof by contradiction, which could make it a bit clearer but it seems very clear to me like this.

Comment: Thank you! I will correct the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any relation $R\subseteq X\times Y$, we have that $R\circ I_Y = R$ and $I_X\circ R=R$.

From this, we have
$$G= G\circ I_B = G\circ(F\circ H) = (G\circ F)\circ H = I_A\circ H = H.$$
This is an element-free proof; it is also something you will see over and over and over and over again: same proof holds for functions, and elements in algebraic structures.